# What info to put on a mobile app info site (2.5 min average site visit)

Tags: website-design, copywriting, mobile-web

I'm building a **mobile - optimized website for my iPhone app**. The app is intended to help people with mood disorders, like depression and bipolar to track their moods, events in their life as well as sleep. Here's the website that I'm building : [http://BetterMoodTracker.com/](http://bettermoodtracker.com/)

I expect that this site is how search engine users would discover the app, and I hope to convert them to users.

In my previous testing with Google Analytics, I found that search engine users spend about **2.5 minutes** on my site.

**What information can I convey with my sales copy in just 2.5 minutes to maximize the conversion rate?** I would love to see qualified users continue to download the app (it's free).

- Do I advertise that the app is FREE on top?
- Do I describe what the app does (ex: features)
- Do I foucs on how the app is different from the competition?
- Do I focus on why the user needs the app?
- Do I describe each feature with a stub, linking to a more detailed description?
- Do I show more pictures and infographics, as users don't read?

I'm not sure what to focus on with such a short time of average visit. I heard that long sales copy always outsells a short one, but am not sure of how to apply this maxim to this particular time contraint.

It would be great to see **a few examples of mobile-optimized websites**(they look good on a mobile device) with a sales copy organized in such a way that a short exposure (under 3 minutes) has been shown to drive conversions.

I greatly appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a goal-oriented perspective, your job is to **get visitors to download the app**, and everything you post to the site should be oriented towards getting that download.

I think you're going to benefit a heap more from actually talking to users of your product (reading the reviews, etc.) and letting them tell you what they like about the app, because that's the only way you're going to get the answers you want.

That said, some tips based on what I'm seeing of your site here:

- **Consolidate your Design:** I see a ton of wasted space up top with the logo + menu and "Better Mood Tracker" taking up so much room. Consolidate these two, at least! If you're expecting people to go to your site on their phones, you need to respect their screen space.
- **Emphasize Privacy and Discretion:** You don't need to emphasize the free right away, because iTunes users aren't as bothered with having to buy apps. I would, however, focus on the privacy provided by the app because you're asking folks with mental conditions to use your app and they are going to be very hesitant about "giving an app all this information", especially as their issues may very well include some serious paranoia.
- **"Getting Better" vs. "Feeling Better":** For what matter, make it clear that there's nothing wrong with them for having / using this app. I see a lot of stuff on here about "Getting Better" and I think that's a risky proposition because you don't want to attach this stigma to your app if you want people to use it. "Feeling Better" may be a more appropriate choice of words here because it both provides a benefit to the user and doesn't reinforce this idea that they're bad / broken for using this app.
- **Benefits, Not Rationale:** The site in its current form reads like something I would write up to give to my professor. That about section doesn't need to be the first thing they read, and your site doesn't need to justify why you chose one approach over another -- you need to **focus on the benefits** the user gets from using your app, and if you can shoehorn some of your app's features in doing so, that's just fine.

I wish I could discuss the app itself, but I'm an Android girl, so I'm not going to be the best resource there.

I think once you focus on what your users need to hear to assuage their fears, and get them to be willing to take the first step with downloading your app, you'll see the results you want.

Comment: Really good feedback, I'll change the site and see how it goes

Answer (score 1):

[http://www.amazon.com/Persuasive-Technology-Computers-Interactive-Technologies/dp/1558606432](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558606432)
Persuasive Technology by BJ Frogg might help you here. The first thing that comes to mind is social proof. Can you link to or quote a familiar website that reviews your product?

> Blockquote
>
> Recent Comments
>
> Archives
>
> Categories
>
> No categories
> Meta
>
> Log in
> Entries RSS
> Comments RSS
> WordPress.org
>
> Blockquote

All that can be removed so it's not distracting from your content.

There's two kinds of people. Some people are logical and can be reached using numbers and statistics. The other type of person usually makes decisions from their gut. You can reach them by connecting with a story and explaining how your app was successful.